# SwiftUI: Navigate from Sheet to a new View

Tags: swiftui

How can I push a new View on the navigation stack from within a Sheet. I want to display a list of Lessons. When tabbing on one of the lessons, a sheet should open showing details about the lesson. From within the Sheet one should be able to start the lesson in a new fullscreen view.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var lessons = [Lesson(id:"1"), Lesson(id:"2"), Lesson(id:"3"), Lesson(id:"4"), Lesson(id:"5"), Lesson(id:"6"), Lesson(id:"7"), Lesson(id:"8"), Lesson(id:"9")]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(){
            Form{
                List(lessons){ lesson in
                    LessonButton(lesson: lesson)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LessonButton:View{
    @State var showSheet = false
    var lesson:Lesson

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{self.showSheet = true}){
            Text(lesson.name)
        }.sheet(isPresented:$showSheet){
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("reached")){
                Text("start")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Lesson: Identifiable{
    var id:String
    var name: String{
        "Lesson \(self.id)"
    }
}
```

However the NavigationLink is not working. I guess, this is because the Sheet is not a ChildView of Content View. That's probably why it does not work. But how can it be achieved?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear on where you want to show the lesson view; inside the sheet as a new view pushed onto the navigation stack, or in the parent view behind the sheet?

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but this question came up while solving this. Your sheet acts like its own view controller stack. You can't navigate the parent through the sheet overlay, nor should you. It does seem like you're asking what I was looking for, which is to emulate other apple apps that navigate in sheets. You simply need an additional `NavigationView` within your sheet. This will give you a navigation stack to push other sheet styled views to the navigation controller within your first sheet.

(SwiftUI beginner, verbiage is likely wrong)

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavigateFromSheet: View {
    var lessons = [Lesson(id:"1"), Lesson(id:"2"), Lesson(id:"3"), Lesson(id:"4"), Lesson(id:"5"), Lesson(id:"6"), Lesson(id:"7"), Lesson(id:"8"), Lesson(id:"9")]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(){
            Form {
                List(lessons){ lesson in
                    LessonButton(lesson: lesson)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LessonButton:View{
    @State var showSheet = false
    var lesson:Lesson

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{self.showSheet = true}){
            Text(lesson.name)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet){
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("My First Sheet")
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("reached")){
                        Text("My Second Sheet")
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}


struct Lesson: Identifiable{
    var id:String
    var name: String{
        "Lesson \(self.id)"
    }
}

struct NavigateFromSheet_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigateFromSheet()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sheet is modal view mode, you can enter in it and return back from it.

Actually I can't understand why do you need a sheet in described scenario. As you described it is expected:

List -> Details -> Lesson,

so use consequently two navigation links, one in List, one in Details. This is a native Apple design for NavigationView/NavigationLink usage - navigation from view to view.

Comment: In the App Store in the `Today` tab, you have a similar sheet popping up for each article and each of the presented apps can be opened with a NavigationLink. But I get your point.

Comment: Sheets do not inherit the navigation view from the view which calls it. You either need to use a Button to accomplish this, or change your logic to go to another view instead of a sheet as was recommended by Asperi.